# How do I use declared regex Pattern again in another Pattern?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to match pattern for nested arrays...

I have a `Pattern` that takes care of one array with digits. I was wondering how can I use the single array `Pattern` for nested array.

Here is what I'm trying to say...

[1 2 3 -34] I have this covered...

```
Pattern digit = Pattern.compile("^[(((-?[1-9][0-9]*)\\s*)+)");
```

[1 2 [-34 7] 34] I need a pattern that takes care of this using the previously defined pattern.

How can I recycle digit Pattern for [1 2 [-34 7] 34] sample?

Comment: Uh, there _are_ regex engines which can do recursive matchings, unfortunately Java's regex engine is not one of them...

Comment: What exactly do you need to match and what is your source? E.g. do you need the individual numbers within each array or do you just need the whole thing (or something else still). Maybe there's a different way of achieving the goal.

Comment: A fundamental defining property of regular expressions from theoretical computer science is that they cannot match arbitrarily nested paired parentheses (so called "pumping lemma" to have some name dropping :-) For a fixed nesting depth you may be able to derive something, but it will be ugly. Just in case you think you can generalize then to arbitrary depth: it won't work. You would need a context free grammar parser to match your nested array.

Comment: I need the whole string... I need to check if the string is valid or not.
The valid string is 1 or more integer and/or nested array between [].

Comment: Your "digit" regex is nonsense, and throws an exception at runtime. Can you please check your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your own parser ([src code](https://github.com/ssledz/stackoverflow-answers/blob/master/stackoverflow-java-answers/src/main/java/pl/softech/stackoverflow/regex/SimpleArrayPatternMatcher.java)). I have written something like that. App only says if it is well formed array

```
public class Main {

    private enum Type {
      LB, RB, NUMBER, END
    }

    private static class Token {
      Type type;
      String value;

      public Token(Type type, String value) {
          super();
          this.type = type;
          this.value = value;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "Token [type=" + type + ", value=" + value + "]";
      }

    }

    private static class Lexer {

      private int current;
      private String input;

      public Lexer(String input) {
          this.input = input;
      }

      private char getChar() {
          return input.charAt(current++);
      }

      private void unputChar() {
          current--;
      }

      private boolean hasNextChar() {
          return current < input.length();
      }

      Token next() {

          if (!hasNextChar()) {
            return new Token(Type.END, "");
          }

          char c = getChar();

          while (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            c = getChar();
          }

          if (c == '[') {
            return new Token(Type.LB, "[");
          }

          if (c == ']') {
            return new Token(Type.RB, "]");
          }

          int s = 1;
          if (c == '-') {
            s = -1;
          } else {
            unputChar();
          }

          StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
          while (hasNextChar()) {

            c = getChar();

            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
              buffer.append(c);
            } else {
              unputChar();
              break;
            }

          }

          return new Token(Type.NUMBER, s > 0 ? buffer.toString() : "-" + buffer.toString());

      }
    }

    private static boolean match(Type type) {
      return type == currentToken.type;
    }

    private static void consume(Type type) {
      if (!match(type)) {
          throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Should be %s is %s", type.name(), currentToken.type.name()));
      }
      currentToken = lexer.next();
    }

    private static void array() {

      consume(Type.LB);

      while (true) {

          if (match(Type.NUMBER)) {
            consume(Type.NUMBER);
          } else if (match(Type.LB)) {
            array();
          } else {
            break;
          }

      }

      consume(Type.RB);
    }

    private static Lexer lexer;
    private static Token currentToken;

    private static void parse(String line) {

      lexer = new Lexer(line);
      currentToken = lexer.next();

      try {
          array();
          consume(Type.END);
          System.out.println(String.format("%s is a proper array", line));
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(String.format("%s is not a proper array because %s", line, e.getMessage()));
      }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      parse("[1 2 [-34 7] 34]");
      parse("[1 2 -34 7] 34]");
      parse("[1 2 [-34] [7] 34]");
      parse("[1 2 [-34 [7] 34]");
      parse("[1 2 [-34 [7] 34]]");

    }

}
```

Out:

```
[1 2 [-34 7] 34] is a proper array
[1 2 -34 7] 34] is not a proper array because Should be END is NUMBER
[1 2 [-34] [7] 34] is a proper array
[1 2 [-34 [7] 34] is not a proper array because Should be RB is END
[1 2 [-34 [7] 34]] is a proper array
```